# Menu with controls

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a game that uses sprite kit, when the app loads up it launches the game. I want to make a menu page that can control what happens on the game scene. I tried making a button on the story board and trying to link it up with the game scene but it isn't working. If anyone knows how to do this please post the answer.

[image: This is the game scene, I added a button with storyboard (the gear shape at the top left of the screen)]

[image: When you click on the button it pulls up a pop over, I wanted to add the menu to allow someone to hang there character. I can't seem to figure out how to have a separate vie change the game view.]

Comment: You should concentrate on a specific problem rather than asking in general how something should be done / asking others to do all the work for you. In the meanwhile you can peek into help section to find out [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: And some directions ...Related to the button thing... If you are using SpriteKit, then probably the better idea is not to use storyboard nor UIButton. Because UIButton is added to the view, not to the scene. Scene is presented by the view. So on every transition, you should manually remove buttons and add new ones specific to that scene. Which is unnecessary work. You can define buttons per scene. How would you implement button is up to you. There are few examples here on the SO. You can use ordinary SKSpriteNode (or its subclass). Or you can use 3rd party libraries found on github.

Comment: I added some picture to help with the explanation